# fill na from another column up until the first non na

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to take this data frame:

```
# Example DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                   'B': [np.nan, np.nan, 30, 40, np.nan],
                   'C': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 400, 500]})
```

And return this:

```
   A     B      C
0  1   1.0    1.0
1  2   2.0    2.0
2  3  30.0    3.0
3  4  40.0  400.0
4  5   NaN  500.0
```

Ie fill NAs in column B and C up until the first non-na value, then leave the remaining NAs untouched.

Answer (score 0):

```
df.mask(df.notna().cumsum().eq(0), df['A'], axis=0)
```

Not entirely sure how this works but seems to do the trick.

Comment: You set counts cumulative  sum of notna. So, on the first instance of notna, the column will be != 0. Then, you compare the value to 0, meaning it will be true only for the all NaN before the first non-na value. That's pretty much it. Then the mask replaces nan where the condition is met

Comment: You could also use `df.isna().cummin()` as mask.